# Laplacian of scalar field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, laplacian, scalar-fields

I have to find the Laplacian of the following scalar field, but I can't figure out how to convert it to Cartesian/spherical coordinates.
$$
U(r)=A e^{-j\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}\right)},
$$
where $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{r}$ are vectors. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Is $j^2=-1$ in your question? Is $r$ a vector in Cartesian coordinates?